# iTextSharp fill in pdf

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have an ASP.Net application where I use iTextSharp to fill in a PDF form.  This works without any problems.

What I am having problems with is the fields must be double spaced.  It appears to me that I can not set a pdf form with double spacing as a property.  Is there anyway I can set this using iTextSharp?

Has anyone had the same problem?  Any work around?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Please share your definition of "double spaced" because I don't know what you mean by that. Also be aware that the name **iTextSharp** has been abandoned two years ago in favor of **iText for .NET** (which also explains why the tag iTextSharp doesn't exist on Stack Overflow anymore). You are probably using an old version that isn't supported anymore. The current version is iText 7.1.2: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/

Comment: I was using an older version.  I have now implamented iText.  I am still having the same problem.  What I mean by "double spaced" is I need more spacing between the lines within a paragraph.  I tryed to format my template PDF file, but when I set the value it defaults back.